# Ng-show or ng-if to hide a button when the role of the user is employee

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

Trying to figure out ng-show and ng-if. I want to show a button only when you are logged in as a admin. If the user is employee then the button has to be hidden.

Part of my html code:

```
 <md-button ng-show="user.role == 'admin'" class="md-raised md-primary pull-left customYellow" aria-label="Add a user" ng-click="showPopUpAddUser($event)">
        <md-icon md-svg-src="assets/images/person_add.svg"></md-icon>
        <md-tooltip>
         Invite a user
        </md-tooltip>
     </md-button>
```

Part of my app.js code:

```
$scope.inviteUser = function(){
    $http.post('/api/users/invite', {
        'email': $scope.user.email,
        'role_id': $scope.user.role
    }, {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "text/plain"
        }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Successfully saved a user to the DB", data);

        $scope.userInfo.push(data);

    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Failed to add user to DB");
    });
}

 $scope.adminID = function(id) {
            var adminId = $scope.getCurrentUser().role_id;
            console.log("logging id admin-->", adminId);

            //$scope.user = { role : false };

            $scope.userRole = adminId;
            //console.log("fafdasfdsafadfdfsf---------->",  $scope.userRole)
        }
        $scope.adminID();
```

Comment: Where is `admin` defined in controller?

Comment: I would use ng-if because it will insert the HTML into the DOM if the expression is evaluated

Comment: As additional information : `ng-show` will hide the element in your DOM if your condition is `false` meanwhile `ng-if` will remove the element if your condition is `false`. In both case, you don't see the element, but with `ng-show` / `ng-hide` he is still there.

Comment: @GY22 What is the output of this : `console.log("logging id admin-->", adminId);`

Comment: @Apédémak: it just logs the role_id of the user -> http://gyazo.com/2d7a9a2e798d92988908d527b0fef2fa. more of a check for me to see if adminId is returning something

Comment: @GY22 I know the purpose of this. I just wanna know if the value is equals to the value put in the `ng-show`. If this value dismatch, there is the problem.

Comment: @GY22 What is the output of this : console.log("logging user.role-->", $scope.user.role);

Comment: @CodingNinja; i am trying to log it but it won't work. just give me a second

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
ng-show="user.role == 'admin'"
```

You forget to add `''` in your code

Comment: Additional information, because this is a javascript expression it will get evaluated as one. So any strings need to be quoted in order for the expression to get properly evaluated.

Comment: is just a way for me to log the role id of the current user. i have a model user and in it i defined role_id (which references my different roles in another collection). actually the code $scope.adminId is irrelevant here i believe

Comment: can you provide the values of `$scope.user.role`

Comment: This code is definitely not irrelevant because the `ng-show` is based on it. Is it normal that you don't use your parameter `id` in your function `adminID ` ?

Comment: @Apédémak, yes its normal I placed the parameter in it but never really use it. so it can be ignored here

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of logic on the view. This is just a personal preference but i would abstract the `===` into a filter:

```
app.filter('equals', function () {
   return function (actual, expected) {
       return actual === expected;
   };
});
```

then on the view:

```
ng-show="admin.role | equals:'admin'"
```